# What are the margin sizes in this pdf?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Someone sent me a pdf and asked my what the margin sizes are. I have no idea where to begin without just printing and getting out my trusty (and dusty) ruler.

I have Acrobat X and was wondering if there is a way to tell using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in a word processor that opens or imports PDF and see what the settings are or read the on-screen ruler.